# JavaFX BooleanBinding Partially Working for Multiple Validation

Tags: java, validation, javafx, data-binding

I have a BooleanBinding in JavaFX whose logic is like:

```
if certificationType is not equal to noCertificationType 
then
   return true
else if (certificationType is equal to recordsVerificationCertificationType or landHoldingsCertificationType) and applicationPropertyObservableList is not empty 
then
   return true
else
   return false
end if
```

I wrote a method to express such validation as follows:

```
private BooleanBinding certificationTypeBooleanBinding() {
    return Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
            !this.certificationType.getValue().equals(Applications.noCertificationType()) || (
                    (this.certificationType.getValue().equals(Applications.recordsVerificationCertificationType()) ||
                            this.certificationType.getValue().equals(Applications.landHoldingsCertificationType())
                    ) && !this.applicationPropertyObservableList.getValue().isEmpty()
            ), this.certificationType, this.applicationPropertyObservableList);
}
```

Only `!this.certificationType.getValue().equals(Applications.noCertificationType())` works. The or (`|| ()`) part does not.

How do I make it work? Thank you.

Comment: [mcve] please .. make it easy for me mere mortal to understand what _exactly_ you are after and how your try doesn't work.

Comment: Break this into different IFs and debug. You could make the outer IF the check on empty collection. You probably don't need all those "this." either. Try to write clear code and you'll understand it be able to debut it more easily. :)

Comment: @sproketboy I have updated the pseudocode.

Comment: pseudo code does help top much - why don't you simply write that darn example?